# Is it possible to read a file synchronously as a part of a route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have only seen examples with polling consumer....

```
from("file://...
```

This line just polls the file for changes as  i understand it

Comment: Can you give a specific use case to understand your requirements better?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html for that. Here is an example:

```
from("direct:start")
  .pollEnrich("file:inbox?fileName=data.txt")
  .to("direct:result");
```

Comment: from my tests pollEnrich uses a EventDrivenPollingConsumer which is async (https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/eventDrivenConsumer-eip.html)